# Wordpress calling a path with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I am trying to implement a CRUD code in a wordpress page. I have had several problems, among them the connection to the database. But I have solved them.

I've reached the point where I show a SELECT, but when I call edit.php or delete.php, it gives an error (logical, because the URL I'm at is [www.domain.com/blabla/](http://www.domain.com/blabla/) and what does is add to that url / edit, and the file in that directory doesn't exist.

I can't think of how I can easily redirect to my edit.php file, which right now I have put in public_html (the root folder)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it quickly (although I suppose it is a non-functional patch)

When I call the file, being in the root path, I only have to go back one folder, therefore:

`<a href="delete.php?idArt=all">` it doesnt work

`<a href="../delete.php?idArticulo=todos">` it works

;)

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [admin_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/).